# Using a repeater control in a web part

Tags: 2007, development

Check the site http://www.infotechstar.com/index.cfm?mg=cp.hp.
I have to implement the functionality of the job posting in my SharePoint web part.
The only thing is the top most item should be opened by default and the rest should be closed.

Currently i'm using a repeater control. I don't want to use accordion.

How can I implement the above functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reuse your repeater control by storing it in CONTROLTEMPLATES and load the control in your webpart.

Another option is to use [SmartPart](http://smartpart.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this with a DataViewWebPart in SharePoint Designer, using jQuery to control the collapsing/expanding of the rows.